# Place values from complex data layer into GTM variable

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have no problems creating GTM variables from 'simple' dataLayer, example:

```
"transactionEntity": "ORDER",
"transactionId": "193552702",
```

But can't understand how to take values from object. Basically i need to take values from this dataLayer:

```
var dataLayer = [({
    "productReviews": [{
        "name": "Donna S. - Stockton, CA",
        "datePublished": "2016-01-01",
        "ratingValue": "5",
        "reviewBody": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
    }, {
        "name": "Sharon N. - Belfast, UK",
        "datePublished": "2016-02-01",
        "ratingValue": "5",
        "reviewBody": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam."
    }, {
        "name": "Elizabeth M. - Richmond, VA",
        "datePublished": "2016-03-01",
        "ratingValue": "5",
        "reviewBody": "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos."
    }],
})]
```

And pass name, datePublished, ratingValue, reviewBody values into following GTM variable:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "review": [{
        "@type": "Review",
        "author": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": ""
        },
        "datePublished": "",
        "reviewRating": {
            "@type": "Rating",
            "ratingValue": "",
            "bestRating": "5",
            "worstRating": "1"
        },
        "reviewBody": ""
    }, {
        "@type": "Review",
        "author": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": ""
        },
        "datePublished": "",
        "reviewRating": {
            "@type": "Rating",
            "ratingValue": "",
            "bestRating": "5",
            "worstRating": "1"
        },
        "reviewBody": ""
    }, {
        "@type": "Review",
        "author": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": ""
        },
        "datePublished": "",
        "reviewRating": {
            "@type": "Rating",
            "ratingValue": "",
            "bestRating": "5",
            "worstRating": "1"
        },
        "reviewBody": ""
    }]
}
</script>
```

UPDATE: As per vinoaj's answer i've did the following:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "{{dataLayerProductName}}",
    "sku": "{{dataLayerProductId}}",
    "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "{{dataLayerRatingValue}}",
        "reviewCount": "{{dataLayerReviewCount}}"
    },
    "review": [
    var productReviews = {{dataLayerProductReviews}};
    for (i = 0, l = productReviews.length; i < l; i++){
        var r = productReviews[i];
        {
            "@type": "Review",
                "author": {
                    "@type": "Person",
                    "name": "r.name"
                },
                "datePublished": "r.datePublished",
                "reviewRating": {
                    "@type": "Rating",
                    "ratingValue": "r.ratingValue",
                    "bestRating": "5",
                    "worstRating": "1"
                },
                "reviewBody": "r.reviewBody"
        },
    }]
}
</script>
```

but that gives and error "[Syntax error: value, object or array expected](https://puu.sh/AdRbV/6e921110c9.png)."

p.s. I am aware that updating question is not right way to do it, but there is no way to insert code in comments in a readable manner.

Comment: You can access object variables in dataLayer as you would usually do in vanilla JS. Just have a look on countless tutorials eg.: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/data-layer-variable/  on "DIFFERENT DATA STRUCTURES" section.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with objects passed to the data layer, do the following.

**Step 1**

Create a data layer variable for the key `productReviews`.

Name your variable `DLV - productReviews` or something similar that is simple yet descriptive.

**Step 2**

Create a custom HTML tag that does something with your object. In the below example I'm simply outputting the values of each review. In your case, you can modify the below to generate a JSON+LD object.

```
<script>
  var productReviews = {{DLV - productReviews}};
  for (i = 0, l = productReviews.length; i < l; i++){
    var r = productReviews[i];
    console.log("GTM says: ", r.name, r.datePublished, r.ratingValue, r.reviewBody);
  }
</script>
```

or try this to build up the JSON-LD object as per your example:

```
<script>
  var reviewArr = [];
  var productReviews = {{DLV - productReviews}};
  for (i = 0, l = productReviews.length; i < l; i++){
    var r = productReviews[i];
    reviewArr.push({
        "@type": "Review",
        "author": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": r.name
        },
        "datePublished": r.datePublished,
        "reviewRating": {
            "@type": "Rating",
            "ratingValue": r.ratingValue,
            "bestRating": "5",
            "worstRating": "1"
        },
        "reviewBody": r.reviewBody
    })
  }
</script>


<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "{{dataLayerProductName}}",
    "sku": "{{dataLayerProductId}}",
    "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "{{dataLayerRatingValue}}",
        "reviewCount": "{{dataLayerReviewCount}}"
    },
    "review": reviewArr
}
</script>
```

Comment: vinoaj, i've tried your suggestion, but it gives error "Syntax error: value, object or array expected." I've updated question with code and screenshot. Could you show how it must be, the complete solution?

Comment: @MployBy ah, you can't build JSON objects that way, as you're trying to introduce code into the JSON body. Try my alternative solution above instead.